# PHP to be checked using for and while

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I have the following code which does not seem to be working.  As far as i can tell the predefined arrays are each of the same size - i have 32 rows in my table "homepage" where "username", "image" and "website" are three fields.  For testing purposes the usernames are 1 to 32.  And the image and website fields are blank - at the moment (this will change).

The code i have is:

```
 $sorthpge = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM homepage ORDER BY no DESC LIMIT 32");



$links = array();
$images = array();
$usern = array();



$array_Length_1 = count($usern);

    for ($i=0; $i<$array_Length_1; $i++)
    {
    while ($row_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc ($sorthpge)) {
        $images[$i] = $row_1['image'];
        $links[$i] = $row_1['website'];
        $usern[$i] = $row_1['username'];
        if($images[$i] == ""){
        $images[$i] = "uploads/default.png";
        $links[$i] = "register.php?no=";
        }
        else
        {
        if($images[$i] == "auction"){
        $images [$i] = "uploads/auction.png";
        $links[$i] = "auction.php?no=";
        }
        }
    }
    }
```

You can probably tell what i'm trying to do.  As mentioned all the "image" rows are blank so i should be getting "$images[i] = "uploads/default.png" for all i up to 32.  But nothing is showing in my html.

Just wondered if somebody could point out an error in my code.  Or if my set up assumes something wrong.  I'm pretty new to php.  Thanks a lot in advance.  P.S i will translate to mysqli when i can get these basics working.

Comment: The limit needs two bits: an offset, rows to return. That won't be helping anything

Comment: The offset thing sounds familiar.  On echoing out $images[0]; for example i get offset "0" or something coming up in the browser - some sort of error...

Comment: @Chris Without the offset, it will just limit the results - returning the first `32` rows (in the OP's case). The query should execute fine, assuming the table's name is `homepage` and it has a column named `no` (and if there's data in the table);

Comment: when you're checking for empty image, don't use `if($images[$i] == "")`, instead use `if(empty($images[$i]))`.  The returned row most likely contains `null` and not an empty string.

Comment: To be exact i get - Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\design\homepage.php on line 38 coming up - when i echo $images[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample code, you have the following:

```
$usern = array();
$array_Length_1 = count($usern);
for ($i=0; $i<$array_Length_1; $i++) {
```

As `$usern` is empty, `$array_Length_1` is `0` - your loop is never executed.

I'm not sure what your logic behind doing this was/is, so I don't know a proper way to suggest to fix it, however, if you were to remove the `for` loop entirely and store a separate incrementer, `$i`, the code should work fine.

For instance, try updating your code to the following:

```
$sorthpge = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM homepage ORDER BY no DESC LIMIT 32");

$links = array();
$images = array();
$usern = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc ($sorthpge)) {
    $images[$i] = $row_1['image'];
    $links[$i] = $row_1['website'];
    $usern[$i] = $row_1['username'];
    if($images[$i] == ""){
        $images[$i] = "uploads/default.png";
        $links[$i] = "register.php?no=";
    } else if($images[$i] == "auction"){
        $images [$i] = "uploads/auction.png";
        $links[$i] = "auction.php?no=";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant.  It worked.  Yeah i thought the problem lied at the top.  Much appreciated.  I will accept your answer when i can.

Answer (score 2):

If this is all the code, this is the problem:

```
$usern = array();
$array_Length_1 = count($usern);
for ($i=0; $i<$array_Length_1; $i++)
{
```

The array is empty, so the length is `0` so your code will never run.

What is the purpose of that `for` loop anyway? It seems you can just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Your above code was failing in a few places I think. This `$array_Length_1 = count($usern);` wasn't helping. The for loop was running off the count of the $array_length, which was always going to be empty because it hadn't been filled yet...

Give this a try:

```
<?php
    // connection strings here or db include
    $sorthpge = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM homepage ORDER BY no DESC");

    $links = array();
    $images = array();
    $usern = array();

    $array_Length_1 = count($usern);

    $i = 0;

    while ($row_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sorthpge)){
        $images[$i] = $row_1['image'];
        $links[$i] = $row_1['website'];
        $usern[$i] = $row_1['username'];

        if($row_1['image'] == ""){
            $images[$i] = "uploads/default.png";
            $links[$i] = "register.php?no=";
        }
        elseif($row_1['image'] == "auction"){
            $images [$i] = "uploads/auction.png";
            $links[$i] = "auction.php?no=";
        }

        $i++;

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_Length_1 = count($usern);
```

Is you problem ! Array is empty since you just declared it

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that $array_Length_1 = count($usern); Your array $usern is empty.And you for loop max value is empty. meaning that $i is incrementing to 0.

    `$usern = array();`
    `$array_Length_1 = count($usern);`
    `for ($i=0; $i<$array_Length_1; $i++)`

And make sure your file is saved as a php file as you mentioned your html file is showing nothing.